# What do you call noun phrases used as adverbs?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> I never met him **in person**
>
> These countries were **at war** in the 19th century
>
> you don't have to use third-party
> websites, you can find this info **in game**,
>
> this boiler provides hot water **on demand**

English has a lot of such phrases and they don't seem to require any articles, probably, on account of them not being typical nouns. (that's my theory)

What part(s) of speech are these?

Do you think phrases like "in college, in hospital(BrE), in prison", having no articles in them, are related to this topic?

Comment: Those are idiomatic prepositional phrases, that's why. 5 to 10 for each answer? We're supposed to sit here and think them up? It's better to learn them as you encounter them. "It was all said in jest." There are thousands of idioms in English...noun phrase adverbial adjunct.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an Off Topic "list-type" question

Comment: @FumbleFingers How's that an off-topic question if I am asking what parts of speech are these and if the absence of articles in them is related to the absence of articles in phrases like "in college, in prison, in hospital"

Comment: They aren't words, so they aren't categorised as words.  They are prepostional phrases, some (like "in person") seem to be adjuncts and function adverbially, other are complements ("at war") they are all idiomatic, particularly the choice of preposition is more a matter of idiom than grammar (that's why "at war" not "in war" or "on war")

Comment: Obviously they're ***adverbs***, as you say in your title. There are hundreds of expressions like *(I listened **in silence**, He came **at once**, We put the plan **on ice,...**)*  where the preposition has nothing to do with physical location as might otherwise be implied by that preposition with other nouns.

Comment: They are all preposition phrases functioning as either complement (2) or adjunct (the rest). The noun complements of the preps don't require a determiner. See also James K's comment.

Comment: While I agree with your main point, @FumbleFingers, we have some apples and oranges here. *To put something **on ice*** is clearly a metaphor based on the image of preserving food. So *put the plan on ice* is syntactically identical to *put the book on the table*.  Likewise, the OP’s *at war* is not an adverb modifying the manner of the countries’ being, as is evidenced by such usages as *Countries **at war** often resort to censorship*.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum: I shudder to think how long an "Answer" to this question would be if you had to list, say, *The amendment is **on the table*** as a different *kind* of usage to both *Your dinner is **on the table*** AND *The amendment is **on ice***. And what are we to make [*of **in hospital** patients*?](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22of+in+hospital+patients%22) (With or without hyphens and/or "scare quotes" alerting us to the fact of "non-standard" usages! :)

Comment: The point is that  you basically have to memorize them.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *I never met him* [*in person*].
>
> [2] *These countries were* [*at war*] *in the 19th century*.
>
> [3] *You don't have to use third-party websites, you can find this info* [*in*
> *game*].
>
> [4] *This boiler provides hot water* [*on demand*].

They are not noun phrases, and they are not used as adverbs. Adverbs are single words like "clearly", "very", "almost" and the like.

"In", "at" and "on" are prepositions, so the bracketed elements are all preposition phrases functioning as either complement (2) or adjunct (the rest). The nouns in idioms like these don't require a determiner.